# Should I listen to my parents if they ask me to leave studies?

Tags: parents, human-rights

Assalamu Alaikum,
After not paying heed to multiple chances they provided, yet due to careless attitude I let them go of. Now they are insecure about me starting over my studies again, fearing that he'll leavr again and also it's too late. They are rather asking me to find means of earning or do some course instead of spending 4 more years in degree after wasting 3 years without any outcome. Should I listen to them? Will I be guilty if I didn't and my choice according to my own will this time too?